# I have been tasked to create a foodstore that I can add and take food from, does my code achieve this?

Tags: java, string, int

I have been asked to model a foodstore that contains different types of food. I should be able to add a given quantity of a food type by using the addFood method and remove food using the takeFood method. The addFood must take the form addFood(String, int) and the takeFood must take the form takeFood(String), i.e. addFood("Steak", 5) would add 5 items of steak to the foodstore. I have attempted to make this class and wondered whether this meets what I have been tasked to do. For the sake of this example I will only use 2 food items but in reality there is much more.

```
public class Foodstore {
    public void addFood(String food, int quantity) {
        addFood("steak", quantity);
        addFood("hay", quantity);
    }
    public void takeFood(String food) {
        takeFood("Steak");
        takeFood("hay");
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: kindly post your exact req.

Answer (score 0):

Your food store is missing a warehouse

```
Map<String,Integer> warehouse = new HashMap<>();
```

and, as it is, when you add food you're ignoring the food you were told to add, not a good idea.

These are just some starting point, reorganize your code and explore your warehouse when you add data to make sure you're doing well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, you would need some kind of register where you actually save the information, like a Map:

```
Map<String,Integer> register = new HashMap<>();
```

You would have to rewrite your functions sth like this (have not been able to type it in an editor, but just so that you get the idea of it):

```
    public void addFood(String food, int quantity) {
    if (register.containsKey(food)) {
       Integer newAmount = register.get(food) + quantity;
       register.put(food,newAmount);
      }
   else {
       register.put(food,quantity);
        }
}
```

PS. You are (mis)using recursion, and I don't think it's what you want in your case. Your function addFood calls itself again and again without an end.